# MVC3 return value to modal dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC3, will like to know if it is possible to return a value to a modal dialogue. See example below.

In my .cshtml file, when the "log" button is clicked, it calls the Log Action.

```
<button name="button" value="log" id="log">Log</button>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Input Error!">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    The result from the controller is :
  </p>
</div>
```

In my controller Action i have this

```
public ActionResult Log(FormCollection collection)
{
    if(x+2!=4)
    {
       // return the value of x to the modal dialog
    }
    else
    {
       // save record to database
    }
}
```

I want the jquery modal dialog to display the value of x.

In the jquery script, i have the below

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#log").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    });
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing two things: 1) a container for the result, and 2) the Ajax call to get the result.  First the container:

```
The result from the controller is : <span id='result_container'></span>
```

And the Ajax call:

```
$("#log").click(function() {
    var ajaxUrl = // set the URL for **Log** here
    $.get(ajaxUrl, function(data) {
        $("#result_container").html(data);
    });
    $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
});
```

In the controller, you'd just return the result as plain text:

```
if(x+2!=4)
{
   // return the value of x to the modal dialog
   return new ContentResult() { 
       Content = x, 
       ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 
       ContentType = "text/plain" 
   };
}
```

Comment: I just tried your solution, the modal dialog was empty. But a new page opened containing the value of x. Please what i need is for the dialog to display x. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, i got it working after reading this post

http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx